# Can I set a column's default to be a character string from another column on the same row within the same table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, default, azure-sql-database

Here is the base table layout:

```
create table employees (employeeid int not null IDENTITY, 
firstname varchar(50), middlename varchar(50), lastname varchar(50), 
assumedfirstname default(firstname), assumedname as concat(assumedfirstname,' ',lastname)
```

I understand that the assumedfirstname column is not being created correctly in the above statement; that default values must be scalar expressions and cannot be column names. **That said, the above statement clearly illustrates my intent. That is, I wish for the assumedfirstname column to automatically be populated with the value found in firstname but allow explicit replacement with a separate string later.** In this way, assumedname will always represent either a default of the person's first and last names or an explicitly entered assumedfirstname and their last name.

As such, a computed column will not work in this situation.

Comment: Populate it with a trigger or from the stored procedure if you can restrict access in that way. Default needs to be a literal and a computed column can't be changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set it as default, but you can simulate it with a trigger;

```
CREATE TABLE employees (
  employeeid INT NOT NULL IDENTITY, 
  firstname VARCHAR(50), 
  middlename VARCHAR(50), 
  lastname VARCHAR(50), 
  assumedfirstname VARCHAR(50), 
  assumedname AS assumedfirstname + ' ' + lastname
);

CREATE TRIGGER MyTrigger on employees
FOR UPDATE, INSERT AS  
UPDATE e 
  SET e.assumedfirstname = COALESCE(e.assumedfirstname, i.firstname)
FROM employees e
JOIN inserted i
  ON i.employeeid=e.employeeid;
```

This trigger will update assumedfirstname to the value of firstname if it's set to null (ie is unset).

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/11008/2).

Comment: Good answer.  I think he only wants the INSERT trigger (no UPDATE), since he wants to be able to override it later.

Comment: @granadaCoder Thanks :) The update trigger is there so that if you set assumedfirstname back to null, it will populate it with firstname again.

Comment: But the update trigger will never allow the assumedfirstname to be changed more than once. I'd be careful about that logic.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I'm not quite sure what you mean about only changing once; http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/11008/4. You mean if the real first name changes, the assumedfirstname does not follow?

Comment: No, sorry, I was already thinking INSTEAD OF trigger in my head, in which case the `e.assumedfirstname` would still be the old value when the `COALESCE` is run. I probably would put `i.assumedfirstname` there both to be explicit and so the logic would work the same if it later changes to an instead of...

Comment: Thanks, guys. I was leaning towards a trigger that looked very similar based on my internet research for these cases. I appreciate the inclusion of the update facet as I had not considered the possibility of the assumedfirstname getting somehow erased which would visually break the assumedname display to be used in several places. That said, I am surprised that a trigger is the only real way to handle this desire. I'm not real comfortable using triggers because I fear forgetting they are there and writing queries that would cause the forgotten trigger to have unintended consequences.

Comment: If the table is already created how can I alter the column as set assumedname AS assumedfirstname + ' ' + lastname